# How to add active class to onclick element?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a HTML that looks and I want to click any `<a>` element, it will add class `active`.

First, I have element: `<div id="listURL"></div>`. After click button **Fetch**, it will reload and add list `<a></a>` thought by Ajax.

I tried with sample code:

```js
$(function() {
  $('#listURL').find('a').click(function() {
    $('#listURL').find('a').removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
  });
});
```

```css
.active {
  color: red
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="listURL">
  <a>Link 1</a>
  <a>Link 2</a>
  <a>Link 3</a>
  <a>Link 4</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Please paste your html code

Comment: @whoami sorry, I added.

Comment: What's the issue? Seems to work for me...

Comment: First, I have element: `<div id="listURL"></div>`. After click button Fetch, it will reload and add list `<a></a>` thought by Ajax.

Comment: You need to include the code from your fetch, if your fetch is causing the page to reload, then the context of which link is active will be lost

Comment: Sorry, it reload by Ajax, do not reload page @JoeLissner

Comment: That's no reload at all. You need to add click handler after elements are created, or use delegated events. Scroll down a bit on this page for explanation: http://api.jquery.com/on/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a delegated event for dynamically added elements:

```
$(function() {
  $('#listURL').on("click", "a", function() {  
    $(this).addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
  });
});
```

Comment: You're right and @yezzz have suggested is good. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are trying adding active to current element and remove active other element which are active

```
$(function(){
    $('#listURL a').click(function(event) {
        $(this).addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
      });
  })
```

Comment: You are using a css path, but not a delegated event, which can be used for catching events on dynamically added content (which is what OP wasn't clear about). Read: http://api.jquery.com/on/